# c++ std:: algorithms with reverse order (end, beg)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, iterator

I want to use `std::copy` on a vector but copying the elements in reverse order. Since `vector::begin()` returns a **random access iterator** it seems like something that would work.

Of course, I could use `std::reverse` before and after but that would be inefficient.

Comment: `std::vector` has `rbegin` and `rend` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class template `std::vector` provides reverse iterators. So instead of the member functions or stand alone functions `begin` and `end` you can use `rbegin` and `rend`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
    std::copy( std::rbegin( v ), std::rend( v ), 
               std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

STL has a [`std::reverse_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy) function template that works exactly like `std::copy`, but copies in reverse.